# Using Eval() in combination with checking for the presence of a value

Tags: html, asp.net, eval

I'm trying to do an `Eval()` on a date column and I've just decided that I don't know how to refer to the

`? true : false`

part of

`<%# Eval("Date") ? true : false %>`

But that's exactly where I'm having trouble so I hope my wording in the question title is okay.

Having said that, the regular eval without the `? true : false` part works just fine, it pulls the date value from the correct column. The problem is that some of them are blank so before I do anything else I need to check whether or not the date column even has a value and that's where I'm having trouble.

I've tried this:

`<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Date") ? true : false %>'></asp:TextBox>`

and this:

`<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Date")) ? true : false %>'></asp:TextBox>`

and a few varieties of things like this:

`<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Eval("Date") ? true : "" %>'></asp:TextBox>`

> And before you ask, yes I have my `runat="server"` in there (and an
>   ID, a couple classes and some string formatting), I chopped out
>   anything that isn't relevant to the question

I feel like I'm on the right track, but I don't really understand how to use the `? true : false` part yet and I keep running into errors along the lines of "String is not a valid boolean" or "Cannot implicitly convert String to Bool".

What I'm trying to do is check for a value and if it doesn't have one (IsNullOrEmpty), do this, otherwise do something else. I guess I'm not sure how to write "Is there a value, yes or no?" in the middle of an `Eval()`. Then I can add a CssClass based on the result.

I appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Thanks,

Jay

Comment: `<%#Eval("Date") == DBNull.Value ? true : false %>`

Comment: @Alex getting Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'DBNull' when I try that

Comment: Please show more details. Where `Date` comes from?

Comment: It's a `DATETIME` column in a SQL database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of object you are binding to Control. But you can do this

```
CssClass='<%# Eval("Date") == null ? "ClassA" : "ClassB" %>'
```

or

```
CssClass='<%# string.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("Date").ToString()) ? "ClassA" : "ClassB" %>'
```

And if you output is a boolean, you usually set a property with it, not text

```
Visible='<%# Eval("Date") == null ? true : false %>'
```

Comment: ohhhh okay, do an Eval() inside the CssClass declaration I can just set values right then and there?

Comment: Yep, that is the power of a Ternary Operator.

Comment: also, love the idea of checking if the resulting string is null or empty instead of the column being empty, I hadn't thought of that approach so thank you for that too. This post actually gave me several ideas